# Can I use loops in Spark Data frame

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My data is as shown below

```
Store ID  Amount,...
1     1  10 
1     2  20
2     1  10
3     4  50
```

I have to create separate directory for each store

```
Store 1/accounts
ID  Amount
1   10
2   20

store 2/accounts directory:
ID Amount
1   10
```

For this purpose Can I use loops in Spark dataframe. It is working in local machine. Will it be a problem in cluster

```
while storecount<=50:
    query ="SELECT * FROM Sales where Store={}".format(storecount)
    DF =spark.sql(query)
    DF.write.format("csv").save(path)
    count = count +1
```

Comment: You could adapt this solution for your needs:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30338213/writing-rdd-partitions-to-individual-parquet-files-in-its-own-directory/32835922#32835922

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I correctly understood the problem , you really want to do is partitioning in the dataframe.

I would suggest to do this

```
df.write.partitionBy("Store").mode(SaveMode.Append).csv("..")
```

This will write the dataframe into several partitions like

```
store=2/
store=1/
....
```

Comment: You are correct.Partition by solved my problem. Thank you, Avishek

Comment: is there any way I can control the number of part files formed within a partition?

Comment: Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44808415/spark-parquet-partitioning-large-number-of-files

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can run a loop here as it is not an Nested operation on data frame.
Nested operation on RDD or Data frame is not allowed as Spark Context is not Serializable.